# Action hook to control access to certain parts of my site

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I'm searching for an action hook which I can use to control access to certain parts of my Wordpress site. I want to write some custom PHP which will check certain user attributes and decide if they can view a particular part of the site (ie only users with certain attributes can view pages which fall under particular url hierarchies).

More specifically:

- My user profile has two extra flags: i) member of community 1 and ii)  i) member of community 2.
- Community one consists of a load of content which falls under a page with slug "community1"
- Every time a use tries to access the page with slug community1 or any of it's sub-pages (eg community1/about), I want to check that they are a. logged in and b. have the community1 flag set in their profile. If they do then I allow the access, if not I redirect to page explaining that they need to sign up for access.
- The same for community2.

Comment: This question is way to broad to get a reasonable answer. Please specify -in your question- what you want to do.

Comment: ok, I've added more specifics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the very top of your `page.php` file, before the `get_header()` call:

```
<?php
    // redirect if user isn't logged in
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/signup/' ) );
        exit;
    }

    // supply IDs of both parent pages
    $keys = array( '21', '23' );

    // check if user can access page
    foreach( $keys as $key )
    {
        // get parent page object
        $parent = get_page( $key );

        // add IDs of parent and children to array
        $pageids = array();
        $objs = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $parent->ID ) );
        foreach( $objs as $obj ) $pageids[] = $obj->ID;
        $pageids[] = $key;

        if(
            // check if current page is restricted area
            in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $pageids )
            // and check if current user has appropriate meta
            && '1' !== get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $parent->post_name, true )
        ) {
            // redirect to signup page if conditions aren't met
            wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/signup/?for=' . $parent->post_name ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Notes: (a) you'll have to supply the correct page IDs for the `$keys` array on line 9, and (b) this code expects users to have user meta with key `community1` (and/or `community2`), and value `1` if they have access.

Answer (score 1):

Diggy's answer will get you most of the way there, however, if you want to do all of this before the database is queried and template is loaded, you can hook `parse_query` and look at the requested page:

```
function wpa89022_check_user( $query ){

    // not a page
    if( ! isset( $query->query['pagename'] ) )
        return;

    if( false !== strpos( $query->query['pagename'], 'community1' ) 
    || false !== strpos( $query->query['pagename'], 'community2' ) ):

        // community1 or community2 is in the requested pagename path

    endif;

}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpa89022_check_user' );
```

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile, I also found a hook called 'pre_get_posts' which seems to do what I want. Which runs first between this and parse_query?